# Creating a Quartile Column using average per observations instead as row value

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping, quartile

I have panel data time series, and I would like to create a variable with the quartile of the mean of a given variable so that a firm can only be found in a given quartile. For example, if I have 4 companies:

```
 df = 
    id year value Quartile* Quartile**
    1  2010 1      1         1
    1  2015 1      1         1
    2  2010 10     2         2  
    2  2015 10     2         2
    3  2010 10     2         3
    3  2015 20     3         3
    4  2010 40     4         4
    4  2015 40     4         4
```

With the standard approach Quartile* such:

```
df<- within(df, Quartile* <- as.integer(cut(TotalAssets_wins,
                                            quantile(value, probs=0:4/4), 
                                            include.lowest=TRUE)))
```

I obtain the values for Quartile*, however, I would like to prevent companies from having different quartiles values through time. For this reason, I would like to compute the value of the quartile given the average of all observations per firm, to obtain the values for Quartile**. The key difference is that they are firm dependent values. Any idea on how to implement this in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method using `tapply`, `rank`, and `split`.

```
# create 0 vector
dat$q <- 0
# fill it in
split(dat$q, dat$id) <- rank(tapply(dat$value, dat$id, FUN=mean))
```

Here, `tapply` calculates the mean by ID, and `rank` ranks these means. We feed this ranking into column q of the data.frame using `split`. As a side note, because `tapply` and `split` will order the observations into the same groups in the same order, the observations do not have to be in any particular order for this to work.

This returns

```
dat
  id year value Quartile. Quartile.. q
1  1 2010     1         1          1 1
2  1 2015     1         1          1 1
3  2 2010    10         2          2 2
4  2 2015    10         2          2 2
5  3 2010    10         2          3 3
6  3 2015    20         3          3 3
7  4 2010    40         4          4 4
8  4 2015    40         4          4 4
```

where the q column matches the desired values in the Quartile.. column.

**data**

```
dat <-
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), year = c(2010L, 
2015L, 2010L, 2015L, 2010L, 2015L, 2010L, 2015L), value = c(1L, 
1L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 20L, 40L, 40L), Quartile. = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), Quartile.. = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L)), .Names = c("id", "year", "value", "Quartile.", "Quartile.."
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```